# Button added to tableview cell appears on other random cells as well

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uibutton

I'm experiencing a problem with regards to adding a button to a tableview cell. Basically, I'm adding a button to a specific cell, but that button also appears on random other cells (not currently in the view).

When I tap a cell, I set a variable (`tappedCell=indexPath`), and reload that cell. In my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` I check if the `indexPath` is equal to the `tappedCell`, and if it is I add a button to it. That works, but this button also appears on other cells further down in the `tableView`. These cells are not in the view when I tap it, but further down, so I have to scroll to see them. If I keep scrolling up and down (quickly), more and more cells with buttons appears. This seems to be completely random.

I've tried adding a `NSLog()` inside the `if-statement` where I add the button, but this is not called more than once (when I tap the original cell). So it's actually not adding more buttons, it has to be the same one appearing in multiple cells.

I have no idea why this is happening. I've tried adding a button to every cell, and then just set `hidden = YES` as standard, and `hidden = NO` when the `[self.tappedCell isEqual:indexPath]`, but this does not change anything...

Here you can see the code I use to add the button to my cell:

```
UIButton *newBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[newBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"open.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[newBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(220, 0, 100, 86)];
[newBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(openImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];                
[cell.contentView addSubview:newBtn];
```

I don't know what I'm doing wrong, or if I am doing something wrong at all. It's worth mentioning that I'm using a standard Apple/iOS `style=subtitle` cell, and not a custom one. This is to keep it consistent throughout my app (The cells are made in the storyboard, and I'm reusing a prototype cell).

Could anyone give me any insight on why it's behaving like it does, and how I can fix it?

Thanks in advance!

**EDIT 1:**

Here's my full code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    // Set up the item
    XYZItem *item = [self.itemsInView objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *CellIdentifier = @"itemPrototypeCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = item.itemName;

    if ([self.selectedItem isEqual:indexPath]) 
    {
        cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;

        UIButton *newBtn=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        [newBtn setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"open.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [newBtn setFrame:CGRectMake(220, 0, 100, 86)];
        [newBtn addTarget:self action:@selector(openImage:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

        [cell.contentView addSubview:newBtn];
    }

    NSString *detailTextLabelText = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu subitems", (unsigned long)[item.subItems count]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = detailTextLabelText;

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button is showing up on cells that have reused a button that previously added it.

There are a few options here.

1. Make the button part of every cell.  Set it's `.hidden` property every time you create/reuse one to the appropriate value.
2. Remove the button in the cell's `prepareForReuse` method.

---

Assuming `self.tappedCell` is a `UITableViewCell` subclass and `indexPath` is an index path, `[self.tappedCell isEqual:indexPath]` will always return `NO`

Comment: Hi, and thanks for your quick feedback! :)

I'm sorry, I understand the confusion: `self.tappedCell` is a `indexPath` (of the tapped cell). So I don't think that's a problem.

Now, what you're saying is that the button is showing up on cells that previously had the button? Or am I misunderstanding? I don't see how that can be, because the problem occurs at the first tap. Even if it's the first cell I'm tapping, the button still shows up on other cells further down. And as I keep scrolling up and down (quickly), it also appears on more cells (even though my add-button-if-statement does not run)

Comment: And I tried making the button a part of every cell, and just set the `.hidden` property. That did not make a difference (but maybe I did it wrong). I'll add my entire code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath` as an edit to my post and you can have a look at it :)

Comment: Yes.  You're REUSING cells.  That's how table views work.  Let's say your table view is big enough to fit 10 cells on screen at the same time.  As the 1st cell scrolls off and the 11th cell scrolls on, the 1st cell is reused as the 11th cell.  The only reuse you're noticing is button, because you're never removing it.

Comment: Your absolute best option would be to subclass `UITableViewCell` and use that.

Comment: Ohhh, now I understand. Thanks for explaining how the tableview works, I did not know that..!

Furthermore, how would I do that? I'm new to iOS development, so I'm sorry if this is something really basic I should know... But I'm getting there :)

Comment: Is the exact same process by which you subclass `UIViewController` and then link the view controller in the storyboard to the new file you just made.  Just choose to subclass `UITableViewCell` instead.

Comment: So I make a separate file of type `UITableViewCell`, and add everything from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` into there? And then I..? I'm not quite following here. Do you know of a good tutorial explaining this concept? Or maybe if you have time could show me how I would reference that new document/cell in my `ViewController` file?

Comment: http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1 This is a decent starting point.  Scroll about 2/3rds of the way down.  Read the sections titled "Prototype Cells", "Designing Your Own Prototype Cells", and "Using a Subclass for the Cell"

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue and i also had multiple headers:

The solution is:

```
    if (!cell)
    {
      cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];


        headerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:
                                CGRectMake(15, 5, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 15.0)];

        headerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        headerLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        [headerLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica Neue Medium" size:13.0]];
        headerLabel.tag = 1002;
         [cell.contentView addSubview:headerLabel];

        button =  [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.size.width, HEIGHTROW)];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(eventAddAlert) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"add_manually.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        button.hidden = YES;
        button.tag = 1001;


      [cell.contentView addSubview:button];

    }else{

            // use viewWithTag to find lblNombre in the re-usable cell.contentView

         headerLabel = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1002];
        button = (UIButton *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:1001];

    }

 if(indexPath.section == 0 && indexPath.row == 0){

        button.hidden = NO;


    }else{
       button.hidden = YES;
         .........
}
```

.........